# Shell scripting: How can I automate the reboot of my router?

Tags: shell, automation

Those are the **commands** I issue to reboot my DSL router when the line is down:

```
luis@balanceador:~$ telnet 192.168.3.1
Trying 192.168.3.1...
Connected to 192.168.3.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

User Access Verification

Username: 1234

Password:

$sh
ADSL#restart
```

Is there any way to **automate** this on shell scripting?

I have heard that [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) can solve it. It would be a fine solution, as long as Screen works on Linux, BSD and even Windows (via CygWin).
Other solutions are accepted too, as long as they are valid for shell scripts.

Comment: I really don't know how screen would help. But why don't you just pipe the required characters to telnet?

Comment: It would be a valid solution, @SamiKuhmonen. If it works, of course.